# Extract <a href> html text between sibling nodes

Tags: html, parsing, xpath, nodes, between

I'm trying to extract the text containing abbreviated educational degree information (e.g., MA, BA) between the parenthesis nodes in the following table. I can extract all the nodes including the parenthesis using xpath, iterate over them, and add some logic, but I was curious if there exists a more efficient way to extract the  text between the parenthesis.

xpath("//tr/td[@class='infobox-data'][starts-with(text(), ' (')]//following-sibling::node()")

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="infobox-label">
                <a href="/wiki/Alma_mater" title="Alma mater">Alma mater
                </a>
            </th>
            <td class="infobox-data">
                <a href="/wiki/University_of_Alberta" title="University of Alberta">University of Alberta
                </a>
                " ("
                <a href="/wiki/Bachelor_of_Arts" title="Bachelor of Arts">BA
                </a>
                ")"
                <br>
                <a href="/wiki/Hertford_College,_Oxford" title="Hertford College, Oxford">Hertford College, Oxford
                </a>
                " ("
                <a href="/wiki/Master_of_Arts_(Oxford,_Cambridge,_and_Dublin)" title="Master of Arts (Oxford, Cambridge, and Dublin)">MA
                </a>
                ","
                <a href="/wiki/Bachelor_of_Civil_Law" title="Bachelor of Civil Law">BCL
                </a>
                ")"
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//text()[contains(.,')')]/preceding-sibling::a[1]/normalize-space(text())
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Pavel! I was able to narrow it down using the following revision.

//tr/td[@class='infobox-data']/text()[starts-with(.,')')]/preceding-sibling::a[1]/text()

I just need to figure out how to grab all the <a href> nodes between " (" and ")" that are separated by a comma like in the second scenario.

Comment: Try rewrite `text()[starts-with(.,')')]` into `text()[starts-with(.,')') or starts-with(.,',')]`

Comment: It's a bit long, but the following expression is working perfectly:

//tr//th/a[@title='Alma mater' or @title='Education']/../following-sibling::td[@class='infobox-data']/text()[starts-with(.,' (') or starts-with(.,',')]/following-sibling::a[1]/text()